# Rotating Banners with TimeOut function not working?

Tags: jquery

The rotating banners will not rotate. Im not sure what I did wrong in the codes below. Basically, I upgraded the functionality of the rotating banners in jQuery from the old javascript. There are five banners and each one need to rotate based on the TimeOut function.

HTML:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Rotating Banners in jQuery</title>
    <link href="rotStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="rotScript.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="slideshow">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li style="visibility:visible" class="slide" id="image1"><a href="#"><img alt="AT&T" src="banner.att.en.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li class="slide" id="image2"><a href="#"><img alt="US Cellular" src="banner.uscellular.user.en.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li class="slide" id="image3"><a href="#"><img alt="Verizon" src="banner.verizon.en.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li class="slide" id="image4"><a href="#"><img alt="Wi-Fi" src="banner.wifi.en.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li class="slide" id="image5"><a href="#"><img alt="Wi-Fi" src="banner.wifi2.en.jpg" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
font-weight:bold;
margin-left:40px;
background-color:#e5e5e5;
}

/* begin: slideshow */
.slideshow {
position:relative;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.slideshow a img {
border:none;
}
.slideshow li.slide {
list-style-type:none;
}
.slideshow .slides {
height:230px;
margin:0;
}
.slideshow .slides li.slide {
visibility:hidden;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0;
}
.slideshow .buttons {
display:none;
}
.slideshow .buttons {
display:block;
position:absolute;
z-index:100;
left:0px;
bottom:20px;
margin:0;
}
.slideshow .buttons li {
float:left;
display:inline;
width:24px;
height:24px;
margin:0;
padding-left:11px;
line-height:30px;
background-image:url('buttonBg.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.slideshow .buttons li a {
float:left;
text-decoration:none;
width:30px;
height:30px;
color:#fff;
outline:0;
}
.slideshow ul.buttons li a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
color:#0a0a0a;
}
.slideshow ul.buttons li.active a:hover,
.slideshow ul.buttons li.active a {
color:#666666;
}
/* end: slideshow */
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
var timer;
function button1_click(event)
{
$(".slide").css("visibility","hidden");
$("#image1").css("visibility","visible");
$("#image1").css("opacity","0");
$("#image1").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
$("ul.buttons li").removeClass("active");
$("#image1").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
$("#button1").addClass("active");
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(button2_click, 3000);
$("#image1").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
}

function button2_click(event)
{
$(".slide").css("visibility","hidden");
$("#image2").css("visibility","visible");
$("#image2").css("opacity","0");
$("#image2").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
$("ul.buttons li").removeClass("active");
$("#image2").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
$("#button2").addClass("active");
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(button3_click, 3000);
$("#image2").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
}

function button3_click(event)
{
$(".slide").css("visibility","hidden");
$("#image3").css("visibility","visible");
$("#image3").css("opacity","0");
$("#image3").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
$("ul.buttons li").removeClass("active");
$("#image3").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
$("#button3").addClass("active");
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(button4_click, 3000);
$("#image3").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
}

function button4_click(event)
{
$(".slide").css("visibility","hidden");
$("#image4").css("visibility","visible");
$("#image4").css("opacity","0");
$("#image4").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
$("ul.buttons li").removeClass("active");
$("#image4").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
$("#button4").addClass("active");
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(button5_click, 3000);
$("#image4").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
}


function button5_click(event)
{
$(".slide").css("visibility","hidden");
$("#image5").css("visibility","visible");
$("#image5").css("opacity","0");
$("#image5").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
$("ul.buttons li").removeClass("active");
$("#image5").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
$("#button5").addClass("active");
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(button1_click, 3000);
$("#image5").animate({"opacity":1},300, "linear", null);
}

function OnLoad(event)
{
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(button2_click, 3000);
}

$('#button1').bind('click', button1_click);

$('#button2').bind('click', button2_click);

$('#button3').bind('click', button3_click);

OnLoad();

});
```

Comment: `setTimeout(eval("button3_click"),"3000");` should be `setTimeout(button3_click,3000);`  Also don't reuse code, these functions could all be combined.

Comment: I updated it and nope that didnt work.

Comment: What doesn't work?  I copied and pasted your code (un-edited) and it seems to work ok.  http://jsfiddle.net/qRLQn/

Comment: Thats weird, I copied/pasted the code on jsFiddle and it didnt work. What did you do that worked? Whats going on?

Comment: All I did was copy & paste the HTML and JavaScript (I didn't copy the CSS), and change the image URLs.

Comment: Is it this <SCRIPT type='text/javascript' SRC="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT> that prevents them rotating?

Comment: Try to put the jQuery script tag before your rotScript.js script tag.

Comment: Yep! That was the problem. It works now. http://www.magnixsolutions.com/dev/jquery/rotBanners.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are loading your script before you are loading jQuery.  You need to load jQuery first, then your script.